# Counter examples for 0-1 knapsack problem with two knapsacks

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I came across the following question in [this](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/course-v1:Engineering+Algorithms2+SelfPaced/about) course:

> Consider a variation of the Knapsack problem where we have two
>   knapsacks, with integer capacities 1 and 2. As usual, we are given
>    items with positive values and positive integer weights. We want to
>   pick subsets 1,2 with maximum total value such that the total weights of 1 and 1 are at most 1 and 2, respectively. Assume that every item fits in either knapsack. Consider the following two algorithmic approaches.
>
> (1) Use the algorithm from lecture to pick a max-value feasible solution 1 for the first knapsack, and then run it again on the remaining items to pick a max-value feasible solution 2 for the second knapsack.
>
> (2) Use the algorithm from lecture to pick a max-value feasible solution for a knapsack with capacity 1+2, and then split the chosen items into
>   two sets 1+2 that have size at most 1 and 2, respectively.
>
> Which of the following statements is true?
>
> 1. Algorithm (1) is guaranteed to produce an optimal feasible solution to the original problem provided 1=2.
> 2. Algorithm (1) is guaranteed to
>      produce an optimal feasible solution to the original problem but
>      algorithm (2) is not.
> 3. Algorithm (2) is guaranteed to produce an
>      optimal feasible solution to the original problem but algorithm (1) is
>      not.
> 4. Neither algorithm is guaranteed to produce an optimal feasible
>      solution to the original problem.

The "algorithm from lecture" is on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KX_6OF8X6HQ, which is 0-1 knapsack problem for one bag.

The correct answer to this question is option 4. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46635518/839733), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20255319/839733) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29136342/839733) post present solutions to the problem. However, I'm having a hard time finding counterexamples showing that options 1 through 3 are incorrect. Can you cite any?

**Edit:**
The accepted answer doesn't provide a counterexample for option 1; see [2 knapsacks with same capacity - Why can't we just find the max-value twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31696694/839733) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Weight; Value): (3;10), (3;10), (4;2)`
capacities 7, 3

The first method chooses 3+3 into the first sack, remaining items does not fit into the second one

`(Weight; Value): (4;10), (4;10), (4;10), (2:1)`
capacities 6, 6

The second method chooses (4+4+4) but this set cannot fit into two sacks without loss, while (4+2) and (4) is better

Comment: What's cost, there's no cost function defined in the question.

Comment: Changed term to  value.